# jquery change multiple IDs with regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex, dynamic, replace

i need to modify multiple IDs, classes and names of a div, span, select and other elements.

i clone the html from the last row i have in a table, like

```
var num     = $('.clonedLighting').length; // num of current rows
var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

// create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
var newElem = $('#inputlighting' + num).clone().prop('id', 'inputlighting' + newNum);
```

Then in the next step i modify the cloned IDs like

```
newElem.children('td').children('label.prod_item').prop('for', 'appliancetextfield' + newNum);
newElem.children('td').children('select.prod_item').prop('id', 'appliancetextfield' + newNum).prop('name', 'appliancetextfield' + newNum).prop('value', '');
```

which is working OK. however, the appliancetextfield sections now has many more elements. I would like to replace all names, classes and IDs that contain

```
'appliancetextfield'+num
```

with

```
'appliancetextfield'+newNum
```

instead of doing it for every element. is this possible? how?

to clarify: the IDs, classes or names would look like

```
appliancetextfield4
appliancetextfield4_title
appliancetextfield4_titleText
appliancetextfield4_msdd
```

and should turn into

```
appliancetextfield5
appliancetextfield5_title
appliancetextfield5_titleText
appliancetextfield5_msdd
```

at this point it looks like the number will only ever be single digit, but one day may have to go up to 10 or higher. Thanks for any input.

EDIT:
Trying to implement the below suggestions and lots of googling:
I now have:

```
var num     = $('.clonedLighting').length; // current rows
var newNum  = new Number(num + 1); 

$('#inputlighting' + num).clone().prop('id', function(index, id) {
    return id.replace(/(appliance.*)\d\d?(.*)/g, "$1" + newNum + "$2");
}).insertAfter($('#inputlighting' + num));
```

it looks like the right track but the regular expression and/or the back-referencing doesn't work.

Comment: :Why dont you just change the elements (`newElem` ) id in a loop, based on no of cloned elements in a page or you can even use `.each()` also.

Comment: i tried `var val = newElem.html();val = val.replace(/'appliancetextfield' + num/g, 'appliancetextfield' + newNum);` but that didnt work. not sure how to use `each()` as not each element would need modification.

Comment: No no, your doing it wrong way,your using the basic string manipulation function,you should rather use `.attr()` to change the **id** of a element.

Comment: Can you provide a demo on http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got it:

```
        //newElem is the newly cloned object
    newElem.find('[id^=appliance]').prop('id', function(index, id) {
            return id.replace(/(appliance.*)\d\d?(.*)/g,"$1" +newNum+ "$2");
    });
    newElem.find('[for^=appliance]').prop('for', function(index, id) {
            return id.replace(/(appliance.*)\d\d?(.*)/g,"$1" +newNum+ "$2");
    });
    newElem.find('[name^=appliance]').prop('name', function(index, id) {
            return id.replace(/(appliance.*)\d\d?(.*)/g,"$1" +newNum+ "$2");
    });
```

Thanks  for helping.